# Generate running unique ID from condition in Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to automatically generate sequential IDs when the condition in an another cell is fulfilled.

Example:
The initial unique IDs are previously assigned as column A is TRUE.
I would like for the formula to generate the next unique ID in sequence once the value in column A changes from FALSE to TRUE.

[image]

---

[image]

I tried the ARRAYFORMULA,

```
=Arrayformula("AB"&TEXT(Sequence(if(A2=TRUE),ROWS(C2:C))),"00000")FILTER(ids,BYROW(ids,LAMBDA(each,ISNA(XMATCH(each,C2:C)))))
```

but it doesn't seem to be able to read the if condition.

Comment: Your all data showing `TRUE` in column A. How we will see changes from false to true. Your data showing already unique id created.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the desired behaviour using either a script, or with formulas if iterative calculations are enabled. Here is the formula based approach:

1. Enable iterative calculation in File/Settings/Calculation. Set max number of iterations to 1.
2. Select column B and in Format/Number/Custom number format set the cell format to `"AB"000000`
3. Delete all true/false values in column A and IDs in column B
4. Put the following formula in B1: `={"Unique ID";arrayformula(if(len(B2:B),B2:B,if(A2:A,max(B2:B)+1,)))}`

If you then set a cell in column A to `true`, an ID will be generated in column B which is one more than the previous ID in the sequence (starting with AB000001). These IDs are static after their initial generation, and will remain in place even if the true/false value in column A is removed or changed.